# Download .mp4 video and write it on gallery

Tags: ios, video, mp4, download

i want to download .mp4 videos with progress bar and write it on gallery . I had tried many ways but none of them is working .
I have a direct link for example http://example.mp4 . 
Is there any third party or other way.

I had found that one [How to download video from url and save it in to document directory in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22809245/how-to-download-video-from-url-and-save-it-in-to-document-directory-in-ios) but none of solution is working