# Whats the best way to implement video in uitableviewcell?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, video, parse-platform

Im trying to play a video in a custom table view cell. I am trying to accomplish a feed like Facebook where the video starts playing when cell becomes fully visible.

Im using a back-end service (parse.com) and I'm grabbing the url for the video that has been uploaded.

Should i use the AVframework or the MPMoviePlayerController or implement a web-view?

Answer (score 0):

Defintely don't want to use a WebView. What you can do:

1. check if cell is visible in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` using: `if ([self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows containsObject:indexPath]) {}`
2. download data using one of these: [How to download video from url and save it in to document directory in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22809245/how-to-download-video-from-url-and-save-it-in-to-document-directory-in-ios). Cache this data using one of these: [How to play video from NSData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026620/how-to-play-video-from-nsdata)
3. display using either `MPMoviePlayerController` or `AVFramework`. The main difference between the two, is that `MPMoviePlayerController` is much easier to use, and has a lot of convenience method. However, this comes at the cost of giving up more fine-tuned control.

Hope this helps